# Sudden rain or snow

Tags: phase-transition

From a physicist's point of view, when it starts raining, is it a phase transition from the vapor phase of water to its liquid phase? Is it the phase transition from mist to rain? The same question applies to the phenomenon of snowing.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear, if you could provide more info that would be great.

Comment: Mist consists of little water droplets, it is not the same as vapour. So it is already in liquid phase. Therefore, the phase transition occurs earlier, when mist emerges. Snow, however, indeed arises by a phase transition.

Comment: My question is about another "phase transition" which happens after water droplets are created in the mist already. With no correlation between different droplets they would fall down randomly separated in time. Instead, the cooperative phenomenon is observed when they all start falling down at once. Is this a kind of phase transition and what is the nature of the cooperative action?

Answer (score 0):

**Your question is unclear.**

But I'll try to give an answer.

The water droplets already condense around tiny dust particles, thus making the clouds. When the drops become too heavy to be suspended any more, they fall down as rain.

***If thee edits thy question, I shall look after my answer.***

Comment: Your statements about creation of water droplets are well known and available in any physics text. My question is about another phenomenon which happens after water droplets are present in the air already. With no correlation between different droplets they would fall down randomly separated in time. Instead, the cooperative phenomenon is observed when they all start falling down at once. Is this a kind of phase transition and what is the nature of the correlation between the droplets that results in cooperative action?

Comment: Try one-dimensional correlation along the vertical coordinate. What happens when one drop falls trough the mist?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - I've re-written my answer to better fit the question.

I don't think this is a phase transition per se, but rather a critical density that has been reached.

As an analogy, you can think of a misty window where a droplet is getting bigger and bigger until a point where the gravitational pull becomes stronger than the electrostatic attraction that sticks it to the glass in the first place. At this point, the droplet immediately starts sliding down the window, much in the same way that a droplet in a rain cloud would start falling once reaching its critical mass.

Two points to consider here:

1) The misty window doesn't exhibit the "cooperation" that you refer to in the clouds. But truth is rain clouds don't exhibit cooperation either. If they did, an entire cloud would pour down instantly, and of course rain is not instantaneous. Instead of cooperation, you have big numbers: a huge ensemble of droplets that grow bigger gradualy and independently, but with well defined statistics (i.e. mean, variance etc.). This means that you'd expect that at a small but finite interval of time, many of the raindrops would grow past that critical density, since they were all born and raised in the same environment, thus have the same average growth rate.

2) When the cloud was still thin, it was higher up in the sky, and as it became thicker it sank. Also, within the cloud itself is an uneven density distribution. The above doesn't explain the existence of this unique point where the raindrops start falling instead of gradually sinking further down.

To be fair, I don't know the answer for this question for a fact, nor have I found useful resources, except some weather websites... My guess is that the average height of the cloud is determined mostly by its mean density, but the raindrops' capability of pouring down is determined by their local properties. At a certain critical mass, rising air can no longer support the individual droplets, and they start falling down as (uncooperative yet partly time-correlated due to large numbers) rain.

But in any case, the only thing I can think of that would make this somewhat closer to a phase transition, is if dipole-dipole interactions between individual raindrops were very dominant in the thick rain cloud, in the sense that they affect the critical mass, and more importantly cause the start of the rain to introduce measureable change in the free energy of the system. But as far as I know this is not the case.

Comment: My question is not about climate neither about weather. It is not about what people see down on the ground level, but what happens up there in the sky. I am asking another phenomenon which happens after water droplets are present in the air already. With no correlation between different droplets they would fall down randomly separated in time. Instead, the cooperative phenomenon is observed when they all start falling down at once. Is this a kind of phase transition and what is the nature of the

Comment: This phrasing is much more well-defined! You got my upvote for that, and also I think clarifying the original post would yield better responses. Second, I edited my post to address your question.